# How to calculate average pixel in two cosecutive peaks in x-signature

Tags: java, image-processing

I am working on latent fingureprint enhancement techniques.
during implementation i have devide image 16X16 blocks and then get 32x16
oriented window for each pixel(i,j) and calcualte the x-signature for each block centered
at (i,j) now i stuck on point where i have to calculate the average number of 
pixels in two consecutive peaks in x-signature but how?
i was googling from last two days but not get any solution?

This is the image i am working

[image]

which i have devided in to 16X16 blocks for further operation

Following image is for Oriented window

[image]

this is the formula for local ridge orientation at (i,j) which i have calulated in code given below

[image]

this is formula to calculate x-signature at (i,j) calculated in code below
[image])

Now the frequency is computed by following formula

[image]

but the problem is how to calculate T(i,j)

T(i,j) is average number of pixel in two consecutive peaks in x-signature

below is my java code what i have done is

```
public static BufferedImage[] getOrientedBlocks(BufferedImage[] blocks16x16) {
             int wtheta=5;
             int w=32;   //blocks16x16 is array of 16X16 blocks of normalized image
            for (int m = 0; m < blocks16x16.length; m++) {

                BufferedImage imageblock = blocks16x16[m];
                int width = imageblock.getWidth();
                int height = imageblock.getHeight();
                WritableRaster raster = imageblock.getRaster();
                int[][] pixel = new int[width][height];
                int[] array = new int[1];

                int [][] Vx = new int[width][height];
                int [][] Vy = new int[width][height];
                int [][] theta = new int[width][height];
                int [][]phix=new int[width][height];
                int [][]phiy=new int[width][height];
                int [][]phidashx=new int[width][height];
                int [][]phidashy=new int[width][height];
                int [][] O = new int[width][height];
                int [][] filter = new int[width][height];

                int [][] xsignature = new int[width][height];

                for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
                {
                    for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
                    {
                        raster.getPixel(x, y,array);
                        pixel[x][y]=array[0];

                    }
                }
                int M = getMean(pixel,imageblock);
                int Sigma = getStanderDeaviation(pixel,M);
                for(int i=0;i<pixel.length;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<pixel[i].length;j++)
                    {
                        int x=0;
                        for(int u=(-wtheta/2);u<(wtheta/2);u++)
                      {
                          for(int v=(-wtheta/2);v<(wtheta/2);v++)
                          {

                              for(int p=(i-(u*w)-(w/2));p<(i-(v*w)+(w/2));p++)
                              {
                                  for(int q=(j-(v*w)-(w/2));q<(j-(v*w)+(w/2));q++)
                                          {
                                      Vx[p][q] = 2*(pixel[p][q-1] - pixel[p][q+1])*(pixel[p+1][q] - pixel[p-1][q]);
                                      Vy[p][q] =((int) Math.pow((pixel[p][q-1] - pixel[p][q+1]), 2))*(int) Math.pow((pixel[p+1][q] - pixel[p-1][q]),2);
                                      theta[p][q] = (int) ((1/2)*Math.atan(Vy[p][q]/Vx[p][q]));
                                      phix[p][q] = (int) Math.cos(2*theta[p][q]); 
                                      phiy[p][q] = (int) Math.sin(2*theta[p][q]); 
                                      filter[u][v] = getGaussianFilter(u,v,Sigma);
                                      phidashx[i][j] += filter[u][v]*phix[p][q];
                                      phidashy[i][j] += filter[u][v]*phiy[p][q];
                                     }
                              }

                          }
                      }



                      O[i][j] = (int) ((1/2)*Math.atan((phidashy[i][j])/phidashx[i][j]));


                      for(int k=0;k<w;k++)
                    {
                    for(int d=0;d<w-1;d++)
                    {  
                        int u=(int) ((i+(d-(w/2))*Math.cos(O[i][j]))+(k-1/2)*Math.sin(O[i][j]));
                        int v= (int) ((i+(d-(w/2))*Math.sin(O[i][j]))+(1/2-k)*Math.sin(O[i][j]));
                        raster=imageblock.getRaster();
                        int[] iArray=new int[1];
                        iArray[0]= O[i][j];
                        raster.getPixel(u, v, iArray);
                        x+=iArray[0];


                    }
                    }


                     raster=imageblock.getRaster();
                      int[] iArray=new int[1];
                      iArray[0]= x;
                      xsignature[i][j] = x;
                      raster.setPixel(i, j, iArray);



                    }

                }

                imageblock.setData(raster);
                blocks16x16[m] = imageblock;


            }
            return blocks16x16;



        }
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example that highlights your problem, sample images/data, and expected result, please?

Comment: @ kkuilla thanks for the reply i have uploaded the images and code can you give me suggetion how to calculate the average pixel in two consecutive peaks in x-signature

Comment: That's great. Improves your question and increases your chances of getting an answer. Could you add the original image you are working with without annotations as well? Preferrably the one you feed in as `blocks16x16`. Try to make your question as complete as possible.

Comment: @kkuilla this is the original image which i have devided into 16x16 blocks and get oriented window for each block